# Как организовать взаимодействие объекта с его наблюдателем

Tags: c#, .net, шаблоны-проектирования

Допустим у меня есть класс A. В классе А есть набор эвентов, которые отражают какие либо изменения внутри - изменения коллекций, изменение основных свойств/состояния. И у объекта есть свойство - объект класса B, который должен следить за этими состояниями и производить какую либо работу проанализировав набор всех изменений.

Логично чтобы при создании объекта класса B, передавать ему в конструктор ссылку на объект класса A и привязываться к событиям.

Интересует есть какие либо другие способы, реализации или паттерны.

Comment: В "классическом" варианте наблюдаемый субъект имеет методы ЗарегистрироватьНаблюдателя(IНаблюдатель), УдалитьНаблюдателя(IНаблюдатель), ОповеститьНаблюдателей (этот приватный) и имеются наблюдатели, которые реализуют некоторый интерфейс IНаблюдатель, который содержит метод Обновление(). Здесь каждый наблюдатель содержит ссылку на наблюдаемый, либо получает ее в параметре метода Обновление(). В C# присутствуют механизм событий, которые по сути и являются реализацией этого паттерна, поэтому специально ничего не нужно реализовывать.

Comment: Тут тоже возможны 2 реализации - либо наблюдатель явно не имеет ссылки на наблюдаемый субъект и получает ее в параметре подписчика на событие, либо имеет ссылку и вообще сам управляет своей подпиской/отпиской на события (в этом способе у класса возможно появляется несколько обязанностей, что не хорошо)

Comment: @Андрей непонятно только почему Вы написали это в комментариях, а не в ответе

Comment: @defaultlocale, не считаю себя достаточно квалифицированным чтобы отвечать на такие вопросы, просто изложил свои мысли

Comment: @Андрей: Уже считайте себя достаточно квалифицированным, и переносите комментарий в ответ. (Можно написать ещё «по моему мнению» или там «как мне кажется».)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Интересует есть какие либо другие способы, реализации или паттерны

В С# паттерн "наблюдатель" может быть реализован многими способами, например:

- На основе делегата
- На основе события
- При помощи строго типизированного интерфейса
- При помощи специальных интерфейсов `IObserver/IObservable`

### На основе делегата

Решение на основе делегата предствляет собой классических колбек. Преимуществом данного метода является отсутствие явного, типизированного обработчика события (взаимоотношение между поставщиком и потребителем события никак не регламентируются) и простота метода – при возникновении события, метод класса `Consumer` вызывает аргумент-делегат:

```
class Consumer
{
    public void Event(Action callback)
    {   
        ...

        callback();
    }
}
```

При возникновении события будет вызван делегат `act` и весь его invocation list, таким образом поддерживается множественность обработки события.

### На основе события

Метод похож на предыдущий, но с той разницей, что позволяет организовать подписку на события любому количеству обработчиков (без моделирования отношения 1:1 как в предыдущем методе) либо не иметь обработчиков вовсе.

```
class Consumer
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Event;

    void RaiseEvent()
    { 
        // Не самый потокобезопасный код
        if (Event != null) {
            Event.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer();

        consumer.Event += (object sender, EventArgs args) => { /*  */ };
        consumer.Event += (object sender, EventArgs args) => { /*  */ };
    }
}
```

Метод похож на предыдущий но не дает гарантий на присутствие хотя бы одного обработчика.

### При помощи строго типизированного интерфейса

В этом методе потребитель обрабатывает события поставщика при помощи определенного интерфейса обработчика, строго формализуя отношения между поставщиком и потребителем.

```
interface IEventHandler
{
    void FirstEventHandler();
    void SecondEventHandler();
}

class Supplier : IEventHandler
{
    public void FirstEventHandler()
    {
        /* Обработчик события */
    }

    public void SecondEventHandler()
    {
        /* Обработчик другого события */
    }
}

class Consumer
{
    IEventHandler _supplier;

    public void Subscribe(IEventHandler supplier)
    {
       _supplier = supplier;
    }

    void RaiseFirstEvent()
    {
        _supplier.FirstEventHandler();
    }

    void RaiseSecondEvent()
    {
        _supplier.SecondEventHandler();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer();
        Supplier supplier = new Supplier(); 

        consumer.Subscribe(supplier);
    }
}
```

Это почти классическая реализация паттерна подписчик в C# (и паттерна "делегат" в Objective-C с той лишь разницей, что все обработчики должны быть строго определены).

Реализация этого метода требует пристального наблюдения на предмет нарушения SRP, так и согласованности событий поставщика.

### При помощи специальных интерфейсов IObserver/IObservable

Начиная с .NET 4 доступны специальные интерфейсы `IObserver/IObservable` для реализации паттерна наблюдатель для *последовательностей событий*:

```
class Data {

}

class Consumer : IObserver<Data>
{
   public void OnCompleted()
   {

   }

   public void OnError(Exception e)
   {

   }

   public void OnNext(Data data)
   {
       // Обработка новых данных 
   }
}

class Supplier : IObservable<Data>
{
    List<IObserver<Data>> _subscribers = new List<IObserver<Data>>();

    class Unsubscriber : IDisposable
    {
        private List<IObserver<Data>>_observers;
        private IObserver<Data> _observer;

        public Unsubscriber(List<IObserver<Data>> observers, IObserver<Data> observer)
        {
            _observers = observers;
            _observer = observer;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_observer != null && _observers.Contains(_observer))
                _observers.Remove(_observer);
        }
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<Data> observer) 
    {
        _subscribers.Add(observer);

        return new Unsubscriber(_subscribers, observer);
    }

    void RaiseEvent()
    {
        foreach (var subscriber in _subscribers) {
            subscriber.OnNext(new Data());
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer();
        Supplier supplier = new Supplier();

        supplier.Subscribe(consumer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Этот ответ достоин статьи!

Answer (score 2):

В "классическом" варианте паттерна "Наблюдатель" наблюдаемый субъект имеет методы:

```
ЗарегистрироватьНаблюдателя(IНаблюдатель);
УдалитьНаблюдателя(IНаблюдатель);
ОповеститьНаблюдателей(); // этот приватный
```

и имеются наблюдатели, которые реализуют некоторый интерфейс `IНаблюдатель`, который содержит метод `Обновление()`.

Каждый наблюдатель содержит ссылку на наблюдаемый субъект и управляет подпиской/отпиской самостоятельно, либо получает ссылку в параметре метода `Обновление()`.
По моему мнению, второй вариант предпочтительнее, так как первый "попахивает" наличием нескольких обязанностей, хотя могут быть и комбинации этих вариантов - например, наблюдатель содержит ссылку на наблюдаемый субъект, но подпиской не управляет и вообще ссылка эта публичная и извне ее можно заменить.

Что касается C#:
В C# присутствуют механизм событий, которые, по сути, и являются реализацией этого паттерна, поэтому наблюдаемому объекту специально ничего не нужно реализовывать, достаточно только выставить событие доступное для подписки и вызывать его при необходимости.