# C#: наблюдение за переменной другого класса

Tags: c#

Классический пример: класс `Lamp` , описывающий электрическую лампочку, с состояниями On (`bool on = true`) и Off (`bool on = false`). Я хочу отслеживать значения этой переменной из другого класса (например, `LightingControl`), чтобы этот класс реагировал на изменения состояния лампочки. Из класса `Lamp` не могут быть вызываны никакие методы других классов, так как класс `Lamp` является моделью непрограммируемого электрического прибора. Как это реализовать?

Заготовка кода для ответа:

```
class Lamp(){

    public bool on;

    public Lamp(bool onOrOffSignal){
        this.on = onOrOffSignal;
    }

    // ... 
}

class LightingControl(){

    Lamp lamp = new Lamp();

    // ... 

    // это реагирование должно происходить в режиме реального времни
    if (Lamp.on == true){
        emergencyLighting.turnOff();
    }
    else {
        emergencyLighting.turnOn(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Для таких случаев придумали свойства (properties)

Comment: public bool on {get; set;} не оно ?

Comment: А если вам нужна синхронизация, то код синхронизации записывается в get set свойств (properties)

Comment: Пока не понял, как реализовать. Предположим, что я съимитировал ручное выключение лампочки из класса `Switcher` посредством `lamp.on = false`. Что надо сделать, чтобы класс `LightingControl` немедленно на это отреагировал, если по условию задачи никакие методы этого класса вызывать нельзя?

Comment: Нужно ваш код, начиная с `if` поставить в `public bool on {get {...}; set { ... cюда }}`.

Comment: Если я правильно Вас понял, то Вы говорите об объявлении `public bool on {get; set;}` в классе `Lamp`. Но ведь это противоречит концепции класса. Получается что лампочка включит аварийное освещение, когда сама выключится, или наоборот. Так не пойдёт: включать аварийное освещение должна система управления освещением (класс `LightingControl`), реагируя на состояние лампочки.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, Можно сделать событие, которое будет сигнализировать об изменении состояния лампы. И там, где нужно реагировать на изменение состояния, сделать обработку этого события.

Comment: @maxwell, вот это уже ближе. Вы бы не могли привести простейший пример в ответе?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, Сейчас набросаю.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, Смотрите ответ Андрея.

Comment: @maxwell, такое событие есть в стандартной библиотеке, см. интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx), он должен быть известен вам по экспериментам с WPF:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Lamp lamp = new Lamp();
        LightingControl lc = new LightingControl(lamp);
        lamp.IsOn = true;
        lamp.IsOn = false;
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Lamp : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool isOn;
    public bool IsOn
    {
        get => isOn;
        set
        {
            isOn = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsOn)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

class LightingControl
{
    Lamp _lamp;

    public LightingControl(Lamp lamp)
    {
        _lamp = lamp;
        lamp.PropertyChanged += OnLampPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void OnLampPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Lamp.IsOn))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Lamp {(_lamp.IsOn ? "On" : "Off")}!");
        }
    }
}
```

Связанный вопрос: [Как организовать взаимодействие объекта с его наблюдателем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/710344/218063)

Comment: Наверное еще нужно где-то приписать отписку от события?

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Понял, значт `INotifyPropertyChanged` может быть использовано для любых свойств, не только в приложениях с графическим интерфейсом...

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/710344/218063

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а данном примере смысла не имеет, так как поле `Lamp _lamp;` никуда не девается и ссылку будет держать, но если мы меняем `_lamp`, то да - нужно перед сменой отписаться от события, иначе будет утечка. Впрочем, это выходит за рамки этого вопроса.

Comment: @Андрей, скажите, а как изменится строка `if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Lamp.IsOn))`, если у меня свойство с индексером? `bool this[int index] { get => _coolerFanIsOn[index]; set => _coolerFanIsOn[index] = value;}` Примеров не нашел, а научным тыком не очень получается :)

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, `e.PropertyName == "Item[]"` вроде: https://stackoverflow.com/q/657675/6766879

Answer (score 4):

Для таких случаев были придуманы события:

```
private bool _on;
public bool on {
  get { return _on; }
  set { _ob = value; StatusChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); }
}
public event EventHandler StatusChanged;
```

Также существует стандартный интерфейс [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx), который умеют понимать стандартные редакторы свойств в дизайнерах WinForms и WPF, а также дата-биндинги там же:

```
public class Lamp : INotifyPropertyChanged {
  private bool _on;
  public bool on {
    get { return _on; }
    set { _ob = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("on")); }
  }
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Для более сложных случаев можно использовать [Reactive Extensions.NET](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET).